# Understanding typing changes to of(undefined) in rxJS

Tags: rxjs

I have an observable defined like this:

```
   const orders$ = concat(of(undefined), vm.orders$);     // Observable<any>
```

I upgraded to Angular 9 (major newer typescript and newer RxJS point release) and the typing of `orders$` became `Observable<any>` instead of `<Observable<Orders[]>` which is what it was before. So I lost a lot of typing throughout my app.

Yes this example could be rewritten `vm.orders$.pipe(startWith(undefined))` but forget about that for a minute ;-)

The change is ultimately because `of(undefined)` is now `Observable<any>` instead of `Observable<undefined>`. So when concatenated together the `Orders[]` type gets absorbed into `any`.

The above `startWith` syntax fixes the typing, as does `of<undefined>(undefined)` but that's clumsy.

Here's a few examples:

```
    var concat1 = concat(of(undefined), of(123));               // becomes Observable<any>
    var concat2 = concat(of('cat'), of(123));                   // becomes Observable<string | number>
    var concat3 = concat(of<undefined>(undefined), of(123));    // becomes Observable<number>
    var concat4 = concat(of(123)).pipe(startWith(undefined));   // becomes Observable<number>
```

One way to 'fix' the loss of typing is by declaring the type of `of` explicitly, which can be made into a constant like this.

```
    const UNDEFINED = of<undefined>(undefined);
    var concat5 = concat(UNDEFINED, of(123));                   // becomes Observable<number>
```

Interestingly there's some upcoming [changes in RxJS 7](https://github.com/reactivex/rxjs/commit/6c0cbc4) (which I'm not using) that may be related to this.

So I'm ultimately curious about the following:

- what changed the behavior?
- what is the recommended way to handle an `undefined` observable.?
- if the change is a side effect of a new typescript version then would an UNDEFINED constant in the library make sense (parallel of EMPTY and NEVER)?
- does RxJS 7 address this particular concern?

Comment: This commit https://github.com/reactivex/rxjs/commit/e8adbb5 suggests using `as`. For example `of(undefined) as Observable<undefined>` is correctly inferred on stackblitz but I don't know why it stopped working in your example. I would be suspicious this has something to do with a new TypeScript version. `undefined` isn't tested with dtslint either https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec-dtslint/observables/of-spec.ts so maybe it is a bug?

Comment: I did see that comment about `as` but that's even worse! I also thought that comment was really saying you could put `as Observable<number>` at the end - but I often don't have a named type to do that with. I'm perfectly happy to use my `UNDEFINED` constant but I like to understand these things in depth as much as possible.

Comment: well generics will be remove in RxJS 8 https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/of.ts#L34 so `as` will be probably the only option :). I'm sorry, I don't have any better insight into this.

Comment: @martin thanks for your quick answer :-) more curiousity than anything - but I need to definitely read up on this v8 change because I need to make sure it doesn't break some of the clever things I'm doing! as long as they don't take away the generic in `pipe<T>` I should be fine

Comment: According to that comment only the generic signature when not passing any argument will be removed (in favor of inferring to never), not generic signatures of of() altogether.